# URL Rewrite Duplicates and Product URL

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite

My headache begins with a common URL Rewrite issue. I am running Magento 2.3 and rely heavily on an extension called Firebear Import / Export to handle my suppliers CSV feed imports.

Let's say in this example, I currently have no products and then run the import one by one until all 4 of my suppliers products are in the shop (note that a percentage of products will be duplicated as each supplier are in the same trade) - the import runs smoothly and Magento generates the URLs as it should.

Here lies where I am stuck, the URL paths for the products display as such:

https://www.terabytecomponents.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/6316/s/samsung-200-s22e200b-led-display-54-6-cm-21-5-full-hd-black/category/10/

I need the URLs to be displayed showing the full category path, yes I have changed all the settings in admin such as

**Use Categories Path for Product URLs = Yes**

This doesn't make a difference even after a reindex and cache clean. Here's the catch, I purchased an extension that regenerates URLs and when I run it (takes about 20 minutes) the category path shows properly in the URL! Fantastic until i run a product import job, it now throws errors like this:

```
Some URL paths already exist in the url_rewrite table and not related to Product ID: 5013. Please remove them and execute this command again. 

('hp-elitedesk-800-g4-3-2-ghz-8th-gen-intelr-coretm-i7-i7-8700-black-silver-sff-pc-1', 'computing/desktop-computing/hp-elitedesk-800-g4-3-2-ghz-8th-gen-intelr-coretm-i7-i7-8700-black-silver-sff-pc-1');
```

The import completes but the products that display in these errors will not update, meaning prices and quantity will never change and that's not good.

I am desperate to get the category paths shown but do not use the 3rd party extension as it creates an issue in my product imports.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't Magento allowing the category path to be shown even though I'm telling it to?
2. How can i get it to work properly without using 3rd party extensions?

Comment: Id suggest redeploying removing var/view_processed and /generation see if this works i had a similar issue regarding urls on a multi store

Comment: Hi Dava, thanks. I'll give that a go now and will let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: so you have checked that all store views are set to yes as if the default is set to yes and the store view is unchecked to use default this may cause a issue. Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs

Comment: If that doesnt work id suggest installing https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites i have used this previously and worked like a charm

Comment: I have checked and the settings are correct. I have that extension installed and used it many times, it's great and will sort out the category paths temporarily until the next supplier import runs then magento shows the bad url paths again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93481/discussion-between-dava-gordon-and-mehdi-rafiai).

Answer (score 1):

From much research and a lengthy conversation with a friendly developer at webpanda solutions, i purchased this module https://webpanda-solutions.com/url-rewrites-regenerate-and-customize.html

After installing i still had some problems, but after the settings were customised, I was able to start importing the products using the firebear module, no more errors and the category path is exactly how I wanted it.

This script was also provided to add to the import module:

```
    $this->collectionFactory - Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
$this->urlPersist - Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlPersistInterface
$this->productUrlRewriteGenerator - Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator

pIds - all product IDs that were processed

$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addIdFilter($pIds);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'url_path', 'url_key', 'store_id']);

// this should be 1 if you intend to keep redirects to old urls, 0 if you don't want to keep them
$saveRewrites = 1;
foreach($collection->getItems() as $product) {
    $product->setStoreId(0);
    $product->setData('save_rewrites_history', $saveRewrites);

    if (!$saveRewrites) {
        $this->urlPersist->deleteByData([
            \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::ENTITY_ID => $product->getId(),
            \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE => \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE,
            \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::REDIRECT_TYPE => 0,
            \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => 0
        ]);
    }
    try {
        $this->urlPersist->replace(
            $this->productUrlRewriteGenerator->generate($product)
        );
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar problem with the same error message. I think the problem of the message

> Some URL paths already exist in the url_rewrite table and are not related
> to Product ID:

are duplicate products or identical paths for different products. If you add two products with the same name Magento try to create the same rewrite_urls (the error message occurs for creating the url_rewrite of the second product). I found now a way to fix this problem without an extension.

I also could solve the problem with the commercial extension from https://webpanda-solutions.com/url-rewrites-regenerate-and-customize.html. This extension introduces new a new url-layout that includes the SKU. Now the rewrite_url is different for the same products and a full reorganization at CLI fixes all URLs.